# getting null values while reading from csv file

Tags: php, regex

I have a csv file which has a word for each row like this

```
word1
word2
word3
```

And have the following code to read the data:

```
$arr = array();
$fh = fopen('path/to/file', 'r');
while (($rows = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
 print_r($rows);
 if (!in_array($rows[0], $arr))
  $arr[] = "'".trim($rows[0])."'";
}
fclose($fh);
print_r($arr);
```

The problem is im getting empty strings/null for $rows[0] and im quite sure the data is there.

```
Array ( [0] => )
Array ( [0] => )
Array ( [0] => )

Array ( [0] => '' [1] => '' [2] => '' [3] => '' )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: php version? If < 5, then line length param is not optional (?)

Comment: PHP 5.3.1, so its optional ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read the words into an array? Replace all that with just:

```
$arr = file('/path/to/file');
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: i need them to be single qouted, any idea aside from doing a foreach loop? doesn't seem to have an option for it

Comment: not quite sure how that will affect other parts of code particularly parts having regex patterns but will try it out thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce. I'm assuming there is something wrong with your file format. Most likely there is an empty line on top (which I'm not quite sure, but might fail the `!== false` test).

Better try:

```
$arr = array_map("str_getcsv", file("words.csv"));
print_r($arr);
```

And if you need to re-add the quotes, do a separate loop.

Comment: $fh = fopen('path/to/file', 'rb'); forgot to add b option, but will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The file reading part has already been answered, but about your loop to add the quotes, you could use [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
function add_quotes(&$item)
{
    $item = "'" . $item . "'";
}

array_walk($arr, "add_quotes");
```

Comment: much faster that simply doing a loop?

Comment: @madkris it should be as it´s baked natively into php. You´d have to test though for exact numbers...